# How to multiply values from different coloumn in jsp servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to multiply resultSet.getInt("price") with resultSet.getInt("quantity")

And give the result in my html
How can i do it? P.s im a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below....

```
<% int price = resultSet.getInt("price");
   int qty = resultSet.getInt("quqntity");
   int value = price * qty;
%>

Result Value (price * quantity)  = <% = value %>
```

Please let me know if you have any further queries

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, now i want to ask how can i adding that value(s) from many row. How can i make it into grandtotal? Sorry my english is lacking :(

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help...!

```
 <%
int grandtotal=0;
while(resultSet.next()){
int price = resultSet.getInt("price");  
int quantity = resultSet.getInt("quqntity");  
grandtotal =grandtotal+(price * quantity); 
}
```

%>
   Result=<%=grandtotal%>.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, now i want to ask how can i adding that result(s) from many row. How can i make it into grandtotal? Sorry my english is lacking :(